# Highcharts spline chart not rendering in IE and mozilla

Tags: browser, highcharts, compatibility

My codes works perfect in Chrome but doesn't render in IE and FF.

```
Find the codes here: https://jsfiddle.net/smylla/on35n04v/1/
```

What could be the problem. Please help.

Comment: If you look in the console in IE (have your fiddle open and hit F12) you can see you have some errors. Chrome is able to handle this error.

Comment: Can you tell what is causing the errors from the provided codes?

Comment: My guess is you have CORS issues from the fiddle to the json source. Does this error happen only in the jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes. It only happens in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with Highcharts. Your endpoint's timeseries value is not a valid date format according to [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

`Date()` constructor has more flexible implementation then other browsers' implementations (Firefox, IE, Safari).

You should parse the date to be valid for the date constructor, e.g. like this:

```
var jdatetime = new Date(value.TIME_SERIES.replace(/^(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d{4}) /, "$3-$1-$2T"));
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/u49xmns3/

Comment: Wow. It works perfectly now in IE and FF. @Morganfree thanks for your solution. wergeld thanks for your help.

Comment: @ManuelSmylla I'm glad it helps, it would be great if you accept the answer so the question will not remain without the correct answer.